# Question about watch variable in Debug

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a UIButton object.

I wanted to watch the hidden property of this object.

But the hidden property isn't the UIButton's property but the UIView's - the super class of UIButton.

In debug view, I cannot find the hidden property. Only property of UIButton was shown in Debug view.

What should I do about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
if([myButton isHidden]){
  NSLog(@"Is hidden");
}
else{
  NSLog(@"Is not hidden");
}
```